# Cannot resolve localhost: Unknown host on OS X 10.8.2, but 127.0.0.1 is working fine

Tags: apache, localhost, mamp

I have MAMP installed on my Macbook Pro (OS X 10.8.2). Both Apache Server and MySql server are in green lights in MAMP. But I could NOT access localhost; I'm able to reach 127.0.0.1. (both localhost and 127.0.0.1 were working fine before.)

```
leihetekiMacBook-Pro:~ leihe$ ping localhost
ping: cannot resolve localhost: Unknown host
```

When I tried to access localhost in safari, it shows:

```
Safari can't open the page "http://localhost/" because Safari can't fine the server "localhost".
```

In apache_error.log, it shows:

```
[Tue Feb 18 14:30:43 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server     configuration: /Users/leihe/Desktop/Sites/.DS_Store
```

My hosts file is located in private/etc and looks like this:

```
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

I also tried flushing DNS sever.

Any solutions would be much appreciated!!